# Database access for different users

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

How to check which all users have access to which all databases in the system?

For example:
In my system there are databases like abc, def, xyz.. and there are database level users user1, user2, user3 .., now i want to check whether user1 can access which all databases.

Im using Redshift database.

Comment: Did you check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523273/how-to-find-out-what-are-the-privileges-granted-to-one-group-in-redshift

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741334/how-do-i-view-grants-on-redshift

Comment: x-posted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/116002/7788

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot, Imgetting the query output as 0 Rows.

Comment: First of all, you were offered *two* similar questions with the total of *three* answers, so *which* query returned 0 rows for you? Secondly, did you try to understand the mechanics of the query you were running so that you could try and adapt it for your needs? I hope you will accept the fact that not every code snippet found on the Internet is supposed to work for you as is, without some additional work applied to it.

Comment: And last, but not least, please don't cross-post the same question on different SE sites. Choose one location; if you aren't happy with the response, flag it for migration to a different site. As it stands, one of the two copies of your question is likely to be closed soon.