# How can I fetch the create table statements of each and every table in a particular schema in Redshift?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

As I am creating a repository of the project, I need all the "create statements" of every table in a particular schema. I have tried using:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE schemaname = 'public'
ORDER BY tablename;
```

But this doesn't suffice as it does not give me the create statement.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate since it the other question only refers to pulling the DDLs from Postgres and not Redshift.

Comment: To get the DDLs, you can use this view and select based on "schemaname"  https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql.  The only thing it doesn't give you is permissions which can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523273/how-to-find-out-what-are-the-privileges-granted-to-one-group-in-redshift/22523393#22523393